# Firebase Cloud Functions - When to return Promises - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to listen for the creation of new documents in a collection, whenever a new doc is created I need to do the following:

1. get the uid and posts field from the document
2. if the posts number is greater or equal than 6 create a new document in another collection using the uid and other data.

This is the code I used which doesn't work, I don't know why.
To be honest I've read multiple times the documentation about Promises without understanding them well:

```
exports.onPostAdded = functions.firestore
.document("Posts/{id}/Posts/{docId}")
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.id;
  db.collection("Users").doc(userId)
      .get().then((snap) => {
        const data = snap.data();
        const posts = data.posts;
        const uid = data.uid;
        if (posts<=6) {
          db.collection("Showcases").add({
            name: "Tokyo",
            country: "Japan",
            uid: uid,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
});
```

I honestly don't know when and where to return the Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any background Cloud Function that contains asynchronous operations must return a promise from its top-level code.

If you have nested asynchronous operations, you can bubble up the promises from those. In your case that'd look like this:

```
exports.onPostAdded = functions.firestore
.document("Posts/{id}/Posts/{docId}")
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.id;
  return db.collection("Users").doc(userId)
      .get().then((snap) => {
        const data = snap.data();
        const posts = data.posts;
        const uid = data.uid;
        if (posts<=6) {
          return db.collection("Showcases").add({
            name: "Tokyo",
            country: "Japan",
            uid: uid,
          });
        }
      })
});
```

This is a very common topic, so I recommend studying some of the existing materials on it, such as:

- Doug Stevenson's video series on [Learn JavaScript Promises in Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA), including the second episode on [Learn JavaScript Promises with a Firestore Trigger in Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk)
- The Firebase documentation on [terminating functions, async, await, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)

Comment: Thank you! In order to catch an error from BOTH nested functions I need to set a catch just once at the end of the first then()?

Comment: "I need to set a catch just once at the end of the first `then()`?" => yes, put one `catch` block at the end of the promise chain (in your case the first `then()` is also the last one). In addition to the docs/articles pointed out by Frank, I would advise you to read this [doc on Promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining).

Comment: Good one on that doc too Renaud!

Comment: Thanks guys, so helpful!